# NSURLSession - Downloading a small PNG image in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsurlsession

Can you help me please. I would like to improve this code, possibly by utilizing `NSURLSession`? How would I change this code to use this construct?

The objective of the code is to load a small `.png` image in the background.

```
NSDate *myDate = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastUpdate"];

NSString *img=[NSString stringWithFormat:phpLinkgetUpdates, myDate];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[img stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
imgUpdate.image = tmpImage;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are tons of samples how to download a single file using NSUrlSession. Try to google first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For downloading the image you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It will download image and stored into the local cache memory.

Objective C:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
...
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:IMAGE_URL
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Swift:

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: IMAGE_URL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

**You use below code:**

```
 NSString *str = YOUR_IMAGE_URL;

    NSString* encodedUrl = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: The image symposizes an update icon, it comes and goes. Cache would be bad.
Can one turn off sdwebimage cache?
Is it also without sdwebimage?

Comment: Check my another updated answer. It might be useful to you.

Comment: @Phil_Austria Can you give us one of your image url?

Comment: @Phil_Austria checkout my update answer. It will sovle your issue.

Comment: Happy to help you. Just request to upvote. Don't like to see minus in my answer.